# Which GridView event to use when updating?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a GridView with ItemTemplate and EditTemplate. There is some text boxes in EditTemplate. I want to update records myself using EditTemplate controls. Which event of GridView I should use? If I use Telerik's RadGrid then what event is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GridView, probably the [RowUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx) event which is fired when the user clicks whatever button has the Update command argument.

For RadGrid, it looks like they also provide a [UpdateCommand](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/grid/radgrid-telerik.webcontrols.radgrid-updatecommand_ev.html) event you can subscribe to to save data by hand.